# django google maps

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new in django. I need a google map in my model. 
1. I tried to use django-google-maps.my models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
from django_google_maps import fields as map_fields

class Rental(models.Model):
    address = map_fields.AddressField(max_length=200)
    geolocation = map_fields.GeoLocationField(max_length=200)
```

and my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_google_maps import widgets as map_widgets
from django_google_maps import fields as map_fields
from .models import Rental

class RentalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        map_fields.AddressField: {'widget': map_widgets.GoogleMapsAddressWidget},
    }
admin.site.register(Rental, RentalAdmin)
```

but when i click on the map in admin interface that fields are still empty .
I used this guide to install it https://github.com/madisona/django-google-maps

2.I tried to use easy-map by this guide http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-maps but I can't see address preview in admin interface.
my admin.py is:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from easy_maps.widgets import AddressWithMapWidget
from .models import Address

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class form(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            widgets = {
                'address': AddressWithMapWidget({'class': 'vTextField'})
            }

admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing Google API Key in settings.py

GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'your key here'

generate your Google Maps Javascript API from https://code.google.com/apis/console.